# Flex How to use forms/modules

Tags: apache-flex, flexbuilder

What is lifecycle of flex' forms ?

Lets say, everything is simple for desktop app (c++,c#,java). We have a lot forms (classes), we have a main gui thread, on events we open/close forms, show/hide them, send them data via function calls or etc

But Does flex have another approach?

What is the best solution to have main form and a lot of children, switching between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [ViewStack](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=navigators_3.html) for this, but make sure to set the `creationPolicy` to `auto` or `none`.

Setting it to `all` might have serious performance impact.

Other navigator components like Accordion and TabNavigator have the same kind of functionality.

Cheers